# Identity theorem for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

This question is follow up to an interesting question I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739476/the-identity-theorem-for-real-analytic-functions).

The results of this question states the following:

> If $U$ is a domain, and $f,g$ are two real-analytic functions defined
>   on $U$, and if $V\subset U$ is a nonempty open set with $f\lvert_V
>  \equiv g\lvert_V$, then $f \equiv g$. If the domain is one-dimensional
>   (an interval in $\mathbb{R}$), then it suffices that $f\lvert_M \equiv
>  g\lvert_M$ for some $M\subset U$ that has an accumulation point in
>   $U$.

I have a few question about this theorem:

1. I was looking for a reference for this. However, in the previously pointed out reference A *Primer of Real Analytic Functions* by Krantz and Parks, I was not able to locate this theorem.  I would appriciate if someone could point me to proper reference of this theorem.
2. My main question, is about the second part of the theorem.  Specifically, I am interested in why there is such a difference going from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is in one-dimension we can assume that $M$ is just a set with an accumulation point, but in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have to assume that $M$ is an open set.  I would really like see a counter example that demonstraes that assuming that $M$ is a set with accumulation points is not sufficient in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
3. I would really like for you to speculate or suggest an extra assumptions on functions $f$ and $g$ such that it suffices to consider $M$ to be only a set with an accumulation point.

Comment: As for your question (2): You could take a set $M$ with an accumulation such that every point of $M$ is colinear. What could this possibly tell you about how the function behaves in a perpendicular dimension? You could add multiples of $y, y^2$ (say), and not affect $f|_M$.

Answer (score 4):

$M$ being open is not a necessary condition for $M$ to be a uniqueness set in higher dimensions. For example, if $f,g$ are real analytic on $\mathbb R^2$ and $f = g$ on $\cup_{k=1}^\infty \{(x,y):x=1/k\},$ then $f\equiv g.$ Also any set of positive measure, in any dimension, will give the result.

Comment: You mentioned that $f$ and $g$ agree on a set of a positive measure then they agree everywhere.   Does this set have to be connected? For example, if $f$ and $g$ agree on a fat Cantor set which has a positive measure do they agree everywhere?

Comment: @Boby Any set of positive measure will work, including your fat Cantor set.

Comment: Could you point me to the reference on this? Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Boby  I don't really know of a reference. For $\mathbb R$ it's simple: Suppose $E\subset \mathbb R$ has positive measure. Then $E$ is uncountable. Therefore $E\cap [-a,a]$ is infinite for some $a>0.$ Hence $E$ has a limit point. By the usual result in one variable, $E$ is a uniqueness set for real analytic functions. continued below ...

Comment: Suppose now $E\subset \mathbb R^2$ has positive two-dimensional Lebegue measure. By Fubini,

$$m_2(E) = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} m_1(E\cap ( \{x\}\times \mathbb R))\, dm_1(y) \, dm_1(x).$$See if you can get the two dimensional result from this and the one-dimensional result. This points the way to a general inductive proof based on the dimension.

Comment: I am not following how does the dobule integral you have imply that $f$ and $g$ agree? Can you explain this point?

Answer (score 2):

For 2 and 3: the functions $0$ and $x$ are a counterexample if all you want is an accumulation, and since a general analytic function will have an $n-1$ dimensional $0$ set, the best you can do is what Mark van Leeuwen suggests [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479881/when-can-we-can-conclude-that-if-a-function-vanishes-on-a-non-degenerate-interva)

Comment: Ok. I see now how these are counter examples.  I see that the reference that you pointed out is related. But can I explain more in the context of this question. Specifically, commenting on the $\mathbb{R}^n$.