# Version of identity theorem for functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

How to show the following version of the identity theorem for real-analytic function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

> Let $g,f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be two real-analytic functions.
>   Suppose, that $g(x)=f(x)$ on a set $E$ of positive Lebesgue measure.
>   Then, $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Also, providing a reference for this would great.

The question was first raised [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260532/identity-theorem-for-mathbbrn/2261108#comment4659979_2261108) and motivated by identity theorem on open sets. Where the case of $n=1$ was also solved. It was suggested that the case of $n>1$ can be solved by using induction. However, I was not able to follow the proof.

Since one can come up with a number of identity theorems for analytic function in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I was wondering if there is a good source that summarizes these result. I found one for complex analytic functions [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Uniqueness_properties_of_analytic_functions), but I don't think it is very complete.

Comment: So I tell you about this result, and then sketch a path to a solution at the link below and you don't even mention it here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260532/identity-theorem-for-mathbbrn/2261108#comment4659979_2261108

Comment: @zhw. I didn't mention it because I didn't finish writing the question. Now it's mentioned.

Comment: If $E$ contains an open set, then $f = g.$

Comment: If $E$ contains a cluster value and $n = 1,$ then $f = g$ too.

Comment: @WillM. That's false as the function $f(x,y) = x$ shows.

Comment: @zhw Amended. Thanks

Comment: @zhw If two analytic function agree on  $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Is it still true that they agree everywhere?

Comment: $\sin (\pi x)$ and $0$ agree on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point. Thanks.

Comment: Following from @WillM.'s comment. If your set is uncountable, it has a cluster point, and so determines your function. If your set is countable, it has measure zero. If it has a cluster point, they must agree. If not, a similar example to the $\sin(\pi x)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ shows no.

Comment: @BigMathTimes Thanks. Note, that for $\mathbb{R}^n$ having a cluster point is not sufficient and functions might not agree.

Comment: @BigMathTimes I amended the result; if $E$ is uncountable and $n = 1$ then $f = g.$ In particular, OP question is true for $n = 1.$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can write this version of the identity principle (IP) as follows: Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be real-analytic.  If $f=0$ on a set $E$ of positive Lebesgue measure, then $f=0$ everywhere in $\mathbb R^n.$

Proof for $n=1:$ We have $m_1(E\cap [-r,r])>0$ for some $r>0.$ For such an $r$ the set $E\cap [-r,r]$ is infinite, hence has a limit point in $[-r,r].$ We then have $f=0$ on $\mathbb R$ by the standard IP.

For higher dimensions we need a simple fact: Write points in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ as $(x,t),$ with $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $t\in \mathbb R.$ If $f$ is real analytic on $\mathbb R^{n+1},$ then for each fixed $t\in \mathbb R,$ the function $x\to f(x,t)$ is real analytic on $\mathbb R^n,$ and for each fixed $x\in \mathbb R^n,$ the function $t\to f(x,t)$ is real analytic on $\mathbb R.$

We proceed by induction. First, suppose we have the IP for $n.$ Assume we have a real analytic $f$ on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $f=0$ on a set $E\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ with $m_{n+1}(E)>0.$ By Fubini,

$$m_{n+1}(E)= \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R^n}\chi_E(x,t)\, dm_n(x)\, dm_1(t).$$

Since $m_{n+1}(E) > 0,$ we have the inner integral above positive for $t$ belonging to some set $A\subset \mathbb R$ with $m_1(A)>0.$ By the induction hypothesis, for each $t\in A,$ $x\to f(x, t)$ vanishes identically on $\mathbb R^n.$ Thus we have $f\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb R^n\times A.$ Now fix $x\in \mathbb R^n.$ Then $t\to f(x,t) =0$ for all $t\in A.$ By the IP for $n=1,$ this function vanishes on $\mathbb R.$ It follows that $f=0$ on $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R = \mathbb R^{n+1},$ and we're done.

Comment: Do you actually have a reference to this result?  It seems standard...

Comment: @JohnZornSu  I don't know a reference, sorry.

Comment: Here's a possible reference:
Mityagin, Boris Samuilovich. "The zero set of a real analytic function." Mathematical Notes 107.3-4 (2020): 529-530.