# Identity theorem for vector-valued (real) analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266493/version-of-identity-theorem-for-functions-in-mathbbrn) it was proven that

> Let $g,f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be two real-analytic functions.
> Suppose, that $g(x)=f(x)$ on a set $E$ of positive Lebesgue measure.
> Then, $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is whether this result still holds for vector-valued (real) analytic functions $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $?

---

My proof idea is as follows: We look at the component functions $f=(f_1,...,f_m)$. If every component function is analytic, then also $f$ is analytic. Hence if the identity theorem holds for each component, it also holds for the whole function $f$.

Comment: Yes, your idea is fine.